# Restore system from DMG (original source disk bigger than destination)

Tags: macbook-pro, restore, dmg

I'm running Lion and trying to restore a Snow Leopard system archived in a DMG file.

The restore destination is an external Firewire disk (160GB) and the original system was installed in a 250GB disk. The compressed DMG has 90GB, and uncompressed it takes 120GB.

Disk utility tells me that there's not enough space to restore. In the post [Copying Time Machine backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14635/copying-time-machine-backup-destination-takes-more-than-original-size-are-hard), there are mentions to Carbon Copy Cloner and `rsync` command. Would any of these help me? Or is there some Disk Utility option I'm missing?

Comment: Will you need to boot from the Snow Leopard archive, or just access the files within?

Comment: I wanted to re-create a bootable disk with the dmg system backup. Posted a solution and updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to restore the system using [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/).

It did as it should: The image fits in the destination disk? If yes, restore.